# Remove numbers from the right of a string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is there a function in SQL to remove numbers from the right (in this case, its year) of a string. For example:

```
Honda elantra - 2019
Ford Mustang - 2017/2018
```

and the results would just be:

```
Honda elantra
Ford Mustang
```

Comment: removing numbers would give you `Honda elantra - ` and `Ford Mustang - `

Comment: There is a manual for this sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want everything before the hyphen -- or `' - '`.

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(col, ' - ', 1)
```

Comment: OMG, you have no idea how much time I wasted. I tried substring, rtrim, and ltrim and nothing worked. Thank you so much.